# Flink set processing time in the past

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I’m using Flink to process some real time data. The test data set that I have has events in the past. Is there a way to set Flink processing time start date in the past?

Thanks

Comment: If you care about the time for processing historical data, why aren't you using event time?

Comment: Thanks I'am now using event time to process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, there isn't". But if you care about processing events with a timestamp that is in the past, or any specific timestamp for that matter, you should use event time over processing time.

Comment: Thanks I'am now using event time to process data.